# How to iterate over features of two different qgis layers?

Tags: python, qgis

ANSWER : Thanks to @nils-werner and @goyo for pointing me in the right direction : I needed to pass the `Move iterTwo = layerTwo.getFeatures() right before for feat in iterTwo :` as such :

```
layerOne = QgsVectorLayer( '~/FirstLayer.shp', 'layerOne', 'ogr')
layerTwo = QgsVectorLayer( '~/SecondLayer.shp', 'layerTwo', 'ogr')

iterOne = layerOne.getFeatures()

for feature in iterOne: 
    layerOneId = feature.attributes()[0]
    print layerOneId
    iterTwo = layerTwo.getFeatures()
    for feat in iterTwo :
        layerTwoId = feat.attributes()[0]
        print "LayerOneId",LayerOneId, "LayerTwoId", LayerTwoId"
        # do something if LayerOneId == LayerTwoId
```

I have two layers, which I want to compare:

```
layerOne = QgsVectorLayer( '~/FirstLayer.shp', 'layerOne', 'ogr')
layerTwo = QgsVectorLayer( '~/SecondLayer.shp', 'layerTwo', 'ogr')

iterOne = layerOne.getFeatures()
iterTwo = layerTwo.getFeatures()
for feature in iterOne: 
    layerOneId = feature.attributes()[0]
    print layerOneId
    for feat in iterTwo :
        layerTwoId = feat.attributes()[0]
        print "LayerOneId",LayerOneId, "LayerTwoId", LayerTwoId"
        # do something if LayerOneId == LayerTwoId
```

This code runs correctly on the first iteration of LayerOne, but then iterates only over the first layer without checking the second layer. The result looks like this :

```
LayerOneId, 0

LayerOneId, 0, LayerTwoId, 0

LayerOneId, 0, LayerTwoId, 1

...

LayerOneId, 0, LayerTwoId, n

LayerOneId, 1

LayerOneId, 2

...

LayerOneId, n
```

Why does my function only iterate over the first feature of my first layer?

More precisely, I'm looking for a result like this which works in the python console:

```
arrayOne = [1,2]
arrayTwo = [1,2]
for a in arrayOne :
    for b in arrayTwo:
        print a,b
>>> 1,1
>>> 1,2
>>> 2,1
>>> 2,2
```

Comment: Maybe `layerTwo.getFeatures()` returns an interator that will be exhausted after one run. Have you tried converting it to a list using `list(layerTwo.getFeatures())`? Alternatively you can try `for feat in layerTwo.getFeatures()`.

Comment: does this because you ask `print layerOneId` only once per iteration of `iterOne`

Comment: The second iterator is exhausted in the first iteration of the outer loop, you will need to recreate it in each iteration. Move `iterTwo = layerTwo.getFeatures()` right before `for feat in iterTwo :`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER : Thanks to @nils-werner and @goyo for pointing me in the right direction : I needed to pass the `Move iterTwo = layerTwo.getFeatures()` right before for `feat in iterTwo :` as such :

```
layerOne = QgsVectorLayer( '~/FirstLayer.shp', 'layerOne', 'ogr')
layerTwo = QgsVectorLayer( '~/SecondLayer.shp', 'layerTwo', 'ogr')

iterOne = layerOne.getFeatures()

for feature in iterOne: 
    layerOneId = feature.attributes()[0]
    print layerOneId
    iterTwo = layerTwo.getFeatures()
    for feat in iterTwo :
        layerTwoId = feat.attributes()[0]
        print "LayerOneId",LayerOneId, "LayerTwoId", LayerTwoId"
        # do something if LayerOneId == LayerTwoId
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to iterate over both features

```
import itertools

layerOne = QgsVectorLayer( '~/FirstLayer.shp', 'layerOne', 'ogr')
layerTwo = QgsVectorLayer( '~/SecondLayer.shp', 'layerTwo', 'ogr')

for features in itertools.product(layerOne.getFeatures(), layerTwo.getFeatures()):

    id = tuple(feat.attributes()[0] for feat in features)

    print "LayerOneId" ,id[0] , "LayerTwoId", id[1]

    if id[0] == id[1]:
        pass
        # code if both id's match
```

`features` is a tuple with the features of both layers. If you need more features except the id, you could transpose these with something like `zipped_attributes = zip(*feat.attributes() for feat in features)` and access the tuple with ids with `id = zipped_attributes[0]`